# Alternative to select single item in multiple dropdown list WebBrowser?

Tags: delphi

in c# i am using the following function

```
                     foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("option"))
                        {
                            if (item.InnerText == valano.Text)
                            {
                                item.SetAttribute("SELECTED", "SELECTED");
                            }
                        }
```

for select an option in following html

```
                  <select id="Suco" name="Suco"><option /><option>14
                  </option><option>15
                  </option><option>16
                  </option><option>17
                  </option><option>18
                  </option><option>19
                  </option><option>20
                  </option><option>21
                  </option><option>22
                  </option><option>23
                  </option><option>24
                  </option><option>25
                  </option></select>
```

how make an function to work in delphi?

```
var
  ovElements: OleVariant;
  i: Integer;
begin
  ovElements := WebTesta.OleObject.Document.forms.item(0).elements;
  for i := 0 to (ovElements.Length - 1) do
    if (ovElements.item(i).tagName = 'option') and
      (ovElements.item(i).type = 'select') and
  (ovElements.item(i).Value = 'Suco') then
      ovElements.item(i).Click;
```

no works, why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Which part of the task are you having trouble with? Show what Delphi code you've written so far.

Comment: Your Delphi code is not even close to doing the same thing the C# code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Delphi code is not even close to doing the same thing the C# code is doing.

Here is a translation of the C# code:

```
var
  ovElements, ovItem: OleVariant;
  i: Integer;
begin
  ovElements := WebTesta.OleObject.Document.GetElementsByTagName('option');
  for i := 0 to (ovElements.length - 1) do
  begin
    ovItem := ovElements.item(i);
    if ovItem.InnerText = valano.Text then
      item.SetAttribute('SELECTED', 'SELECTED');
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, try this:

```
var
  ovOptions, ovItem: OleVariant;
  i: Integer;
begin
  ovOptions := WebTesta.OleObject.Document.getElementById('Suco').options;
  for i := 0 to (ovOptions.Length - 1) do
  begin
    ovItem := ovOptions.item(i);
    if ovItem.text = valano.Text then
    begin
      ovItem.selected := True;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Or this:

```
var
  ovSelect, ovOptions: OleVariant;
  i: Integer;
begin
  ovSelect := WebTesta.OleObject.Document.getElementById('Suco');
  ovOptions := ovSelect.options;
  for i := 0 to (ovOptions.Length - 1) do
  begin
    if ovOptions.item(i) = valano.Text then
    begin
      ovSelect.selectedIndex := i;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```